# How to open a .html document as a .pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, adobe

I have Excel 2010 and Adobe Acrobat DC installed.

I have several thousand files saved as .html saved in a folder.
I plan on doing several things, but at this point, I want to basically convert these files into PDFs. I think I just need to be able to open them *as* PDFs and then save them as PDFs which I have no idea how to do...

I've been able to open them in the internet browser through vba... but not much after that.

Comment: You can't open a HTML file as a PDF, but you can probably open them in Word and then save as PDF.

Comment: @Tim Williams Well, the thing is, when I right click on a file, I have an option to "Convert to Adobe PDF". If I click that, the file will be opened as a PDF. If I had about 100 files, I'd convert them that way, but I have way too many files... Saving them in word seems like a roundabout way of doing it if it's allowing me to convert as is...

Comment: That context menu is likely a command directly to Adobe Acrobat. What Tim is hinting at is that you can create a script in VBA to open the HTML in Word and Save As PDF. I suggest you start by starting the Macro Recorder and doing a manual conversion in Windows. Then reviewing the code generated you can adapt to scale to all your files. If you have a specific issue with part of your script post it here and someone will assist you. Regards.

Comment: You could find out what command is being called from that right click menu by examining the registry, then cycle through the folder with a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

1.copy your url of your .html page
2.go to the http://www.web2pdfconvert.com
3.paste your code there
4.click on "convert" to pdf option
5.now click on "download pdf" button
6.congrets you have done

Comment: About as much effort or more than the converter he already has from Adobe. Does not resolve the OP's issue of scalability. Also from the original posting the HTML files are in a local folder which would not be addressable by an outside IP.

Comment: if they page is static then it is possible

Comment: Uhhmmm, no. Again this does not resolve any of the OP's issues. Even if the folder where the files are located are publicly accessible and he is able to copy the URL of each file into this "app" he would have to do it individually. Unless the converter has batch capabilities? Does it?

Answer (score -2):

eo.pdf.dll $650.00+- .net dll that will convert html documents to pdf.
You will have to write some code but you will be able to batch process the html files.
http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/Pdf/Default.aspx

Comment: Doesn't make sense to pay 650 for a platform for which you still have to write a script when Word can accomplish the same thing with, I imagine, as much effort. I understand that Word does cost as well but seems the OC already has a license or most likely has a license.

Comment: Could be...But there are thousands of them.

Comment: Well with some intermediate scripting you can have VBA do the process a thousand times in the same fashion that the product you suggest would without manual intervention of the user.